# post method of mock server url

Tags: go, postman

I hit the url https://65f1e1b8-f73e-466a-9be3-38d606d4f7e3.mock.pstmn.io/LOS of post method of postman on google chrome browser but i got the error

> {"error":{"name":"mockRequestNotFoundError","message":"Double check
> your method and the request path and try again.","header":"No matching
> requests"}}

but when i did on get method i got the desired result.Can you help me with this?

I expect the desired result of mockserver url of postman on browser.

Comment: Hi, can you add more details to your question? Unfortunately, it's not clear at all!
Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand why you need to use  this URL if you want to muck it use the interface  and muck it there. there is no need to really call a URL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.